# How do i open a local pdf file in the browser with the download option

Tags: reactjs, pdf-viewer, react-pdf, react-pdf-viewer

I want to open a PDF file in the browser but instead of opening, it is downloading. I do not want to change the default settings of the browser.

If there any PDF viewer package which is easy to use, please refer.
I tried like this

first import the pdf

```
import Pdf from "../../../assets/pdf/abc.pdf";
```

then tried to open it like this

```
<a href={Pdf} target="\_blank" className="btn"\>Learn More</a>
```

But it is downloading the file. But I want to open it.

Comment: Do you mean opening your PDF in your app or in another tab?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome browser, select the three vertical dots in the upper-right corner.
Choose Settings > Advanced > Privacy and security. Select Site Settings > PDF documents.
Use the toggle switch next to Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome to turn the feature on and off.

Answer (score 0):

As a user you have full control, as a server you can only request the user follows your desires, but they do not have to.

A PDF application/pdf mime file is a potential source of exploit so just like a user can change settings to block adverts or images they can also block unsolicited display of a PDF.

The browsing client may choose to **download and view** or **download only** or **do not download** it is the same in Mozilla or Chromium, just different plugins.

[image]

[image]